# How can I review questions?

Tags: support, review

I came back to stackexchange after a while, and I remember there was a review tool, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: SE recently changed the minimum rep required for reviewing new posts and late answers: [it's now 500](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186538).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current reputation, 490, is 10 short of the 500 rep required to access the review queue. If you get another answer upvote or two question upvotes then you'll see the review link on the top of the page.